# CIS115 GradeBook app not adding grades

Tags: c++, class, object, math

I'm new to coding, so it's probably something easy. I'm going to post all parts of my code, though I've commented most of it out to troubleshoot the issue.

The assignment is to create a gradebook application, and the issue I'm having is that the addLabGrade function isn't actually adding to the total lab_grade_total, or, I assume it isn't. I suppose something else could be happening. What's weird about this is that it works for the quiz grade total, and I literally copy and pasted what I had for lab grades into the quiz grade portion and changed the names.

I know this is awful coding, but we were given several requirement to demonstrate knowledge of passing data to member functions, returning that data, etc. We were also given almost all the function names and parameters, as well as the data members and their types. None of that is going to change. It compiles and runs without error, but the Lab Average always comes out as 0.

Thank you in advance for looking it over; I appreciate any help or guidance. Last portion of "code" will the the input and output of the code as pasted, so you can see what I mean.

Header:

```
// Filename: GradeBook.h

class GradeBook
{
    public:
        GradeBook();
        void addLabGrade(double grade);
        void addQuizGrade(double grade);
        double getFinalSemesterGrade();
        double getAvgLabGrade() const;
        double getAvgQuizGrade() const;
    private:
        double lab_grade_total;
        double quiz_grade_total;
        int lab_grade_cnt;
        int quiz_grade_cnt;
        double lab_avg;
        double quiz_avg;
        double final_semester_grade;
        char letter_grade;
};
```

Object:

```
// Filename: GradeBook.cpp

#include "GradeBook.h" // includes the objects header

// create a default constructor
GradeBook::GradeBook()
{
    // empty becase there's nothing to do yet
}

void GradeBook::addLabGrade(double grade)
{
    lab_grade_total = lab_grade_total + grade;
    lab_grade_cnt = lab_grade_cnt + 1;
    lab_avg = lab_grade_total / lab_grade_cnt;
}

void GradeBook::addQuizGrade(double grade)
{
    quiz_grade_total = quiz_grade_total + grade;
    quiz_grade_cnt = quiz_grade_cnt + 1;
    quiz_avg = quiz_grade_total / quiz_grade_cnt;
}

double GradeBook::getAvgLabGrade() const
{
    return lab_avg;
}

double GradeBook::getAvgQuizGrade() const
{
    return quiz_avg;
}
```

Main cpp code:

```
// filename : Lab1B.cpp

#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include "GradeBook.h" 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double grade = 0.0;
    int userGradeIntiger = 0;

    GradeBook gradeBook;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    cout << endl << "Please enter six lab grades:" << endl << endl;
    userGradeIntiger = 0;                   
    userGradeIntiger = userGradeIntiger + 1;         
    cout << "Enter Grade " << userGradeIntiger << ": ";
    cin >> grade;           
    gradeBook.addLabGrade(grade);  

    userGradeIntiger = userGradeIntiger + 1;            
    cout << "Enter Grade " << userGradeIntiger << ": ";
    cin >> grade;           
    gradeBook.addLabGrade(grade); 


    cout << endl << "Please enter seven quiz grades:" << endl << endl;
    userGradeIntiger = 0;                   
    userGradeIntiger = userGradeIntiger + 1;         
    cout << "Enter Grade " << userGradeIntiger << ": ";
    cin >> grade;           
    gradeBook.addQuizGrade(grade);  

    cout << endl << endl << "STUDENT GRADE CALCULATION:" << endl
        << "Average Lab Grade: " << gradeBook.getAvgLabGrade() << endl
        << "Average Quiz Grade: " << gradeBook.getAvgQuizGrade() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What happens when I run it:

```
Please enter six lab grades:

Enter Grade 1: 100
Enter Grade 2: 100

Please enter seven quiz grades:

Enter Grade 1: 100


STUDENT GRADE CALCULATION:
Average Lab Grade: 0.00
Average Quiz Grade: 100.00

--------------------------------
Process exited with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

There, all trimmed down!

Comment: TL;DR! Please narrow it down, *a lot!* You might want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: And might I say those are some BEASTLY comment blocks.

Comment: Sorry, it's what the instructor requires. I've trimmed the code to demo the issue, and leave out extra junk. I had it all because I was hoping for general guidance as well, like @BWG comments about calculating the values in the return function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, when I compile and run and type in 100, it gives me random values, such as `-10000428.00` because you don't initialize your variables in the constructor. So I did that, and now when I type `100`, it says everything is zero, except for the final semester grade, which is fifty percent, and the lab grade which is 100 percent.

I'm not sure what could be making my output different from yours, but try initializing all your variables in the constructor. Your averages, should start at 100.00 (we don't want the grade to suffer because nothing has yet been assigned). The 100.00 will be overridden as soon as a grade is added. Your letter grade can be anything, but I made it 'I' to indicate no grades have been added yet:

```
GradeBook::GradeBook()
{
    lab_grade_total = 0.0;
    quiz_grade_total = 0.0;
    lab_grade_cnt = 0;
    quiz_grade_cnt = 0;
    lab_avg = 100.0;
    quiz_avg = 100.0;
    midterm_exam_grade = 0.0;
    final_exam_grade = 0.0;
    ec_grade = 0.0;
    final_semester_grade = 0.0;
    letter_grade = 'I';
}
```

Second, you have a problem here:

```
cout << endl << endl << "STUDENT GRADE CALCULATION:" << endl
    << "Average Lab Grade: " << gradeBook.getAvgLabGrade() << endl
    << "Average Quiz Grade: " << gradeBook.getAvgQuizGrade() << endl
    << "Midterm Exam Grade: " << gradeBook.getMidtermExamGrade() << endl
    << "Final Exam Grade : " << gradeBook.getFinalExamGrade() << endl
    << "Extra Credit Grade: " << gradeBook.getExtraCreditGrade() << endl
    << "Final Semester Grade: " << gradeBook.getFinalSemesterGrade() << endl
    << "Final Letter Grade: " << gradeBook.getFinalLetterGrade() << endl;
```

You see, because you made your functions like `getAvgLabGrade()` double as **CALCULATING** the values, it is bad. Because you call it in a single line, on a giant stream output or whatever it is, they are not called in the order you want. There are two things you can do to fix this: make your getters **NOT** double as the calculation. This would be the correct way to fix your problem.

Or, if you want a cheap and easy way out, just put them on seperate lines:

```
cout << endl << endl << "STUDENT GRADE CALCULATION:" << endl;
cout << "Average Lab Grade: " << gradeBook.getAvgLabGrade() << endl;
cout << "Average Quiz Grade: " << gradeBook.getAvgQuizGrade() << endl;
cout << "Midterm Exam Grade: " << gradeBook.getMidtermExamGrade() << endl;
cout << "Final Exam Grade : " << gradeBook.getFinalExamGrade() << endl;
cout << "Extra Credit Grade: " << gradeBook.getExtraCreditGrade() << endl;
cout << "Final Semester Grade: " << gradeBook.getFinalSemesterGrade() << endl;
cout << "Final Letter Grade: " << gradeBook.getFinalLetterGrade() << endl;
```

Doing all these changes makes your example input work juts fine for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll break my calculators out from my getters and do it the right way. Is it okay to have running averages in the addLabGrade functions? I thought this would make it okay, becase later it should just be calling for the value that the add functions assigned earlier.

Comment: It should be fine, as long as you won't ever need to view the individual assignments.

Comment: Yeah, so I made functions called `setSemesterGrade` and `setSemesterLetterGrade`, doing the same things as `get*` of the same name except without a return value. I also initialized all my variables, like you advised. When the last line runs, everything is already calculated, so it comes out right. Thank you again for your help!